# Auth Nextjs website from getInitialProps with localstorage or cookie and Apollo

Tags: reactjs, apollo, next.js

I have some problems with the auth process on Nextjs project. From the [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo-auth), it stores the token in cookies, but in `checkLoggedIn.js` it queries DB instead of get the token from cookie.

I would like to get the token from cookie or localstorage in `getInitialProps`, but  in `getInitialProps`, it can NOT see localstorage because it's still in server side. Is there any better way that I could auth user before component render?

Not sure is it possible to get the token from `getToken` in apollo client.

My current code is

```
class DashBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const decodeToken = verifyToken(localStorage.getItem('KEY'));

    if (!decodeToken.mail) {
        Router.push('/login');
    } else {
        this.props.loginSuccess(decodeToken.name, decodeToken.mail);
    }
  }
  render () {
      return (<div></div>)
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using [nookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies). It works both server side (for getInitialProps) and client side in Next.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve it after few days of research (honestly, not the best documentation around)

In the `getInitialProps`, I took the headers from the requests and copied them over in my `fetch` request.

```js
Profile.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {

  const headers = { ...req.headers }
  const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/profile`

  const data = await fetch(url, { headers }).then(res => res.json())

  return { data }
}
```

Keep in mind that this only works on the server. For the client, you can just pass `{credentials: 'include'}` to `fetch`